# How to code a half vertical page with responsive image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to mimic the style in that website : https://www.washiarts.com/

I'm looking for a way to put a photo instead of a repeated background image. The general view should present a fixed responsive photo on left and a scrolable content on right.

I have already tried the following code but it doesn't scale the image to the full div.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">

    <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
        <div class="leftside d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img class="img-fluid img-full-size" src="static/img/photo.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 no-gutters">
        <div class="rightside d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h1> Content goes here ... </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.leftside, .rightside {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftside_test {
    background-image: url('photo.jpg');
    background-size: 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .leftside, .rightside {
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

.img-full-size {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: can you give me image URL ?

Comment: its completely works fine in my image

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: Here is a black image with the right dimensions (4.160, 2.335)
https://ibb.co/b7zdGgg

Comment: Here are two screenshots of the results for both screen size :
* https://ibb.co/9NhQ2nr
* https://ibb.co/ky39cXR